# Spring Batch Test Single Job

Tags: spring-batch, jobs, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I am trying to write Integration test for spring batch aplication , in my project there are approx 10+jobs
I want to run only a single job but unable to achieve any Suggestion.

```
@SpringBatchTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= MyApp.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Slf4j
public class JobATest {
    

    JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(JOB_A)
    Job joba;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        log.debug("CAME HERE  setUp {} ",joba.getName());
        jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(joba);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }
   
    @Test
    public void processAJob() throws Exception {
        jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
    } 
}
```

ERROR

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncherTestUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed 
through method 'setJob' parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException:
 No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' available: 
expected single matching bean but found 2: **joba,jobb**
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `@SpringBatchTest`, it is expected that the test context contains a single job bean. This is mentioned in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/test/context/SpringBatchTest.html) of the annotation.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1237) for that which we might consider for the next major release. Please upvote or add a comment if you have a suggestion for an improvement. I also invite you to check the thread on [Multiple Job unit testing with @SpringBatchTest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3699) which could help you as well.

Comment: Can we use any other approach for testing.

Comment: Removing the usage of `@SpringBatchTest` should fix your issue since you are already defining the `JobLauncherTestUtils` and setting the job under test manually in `setUp`.

Comment: I tried removing it and setting via manually but its throwing 
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils

Comment: Are you sure your change has been taken into account? I don't see how this is possible. From what you shared, nothing is requesting a bean of type `JobLauncherTestUtils`, so I can't see how you can get this error.